# Eager load a query with data from another schema in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, eager-loading

I'm trying to improve a get query.

The goal is to get all `Authors` and the total number of likes on all their `Posts`.
Here's my implementation.

```
const authors = await Author.find({ created_at: -1 }).lean();

const updated = authors.map((author) => {
  const likes = await Post.find({ authorId: author._id }).select({ likes: 1 });
  return { ... author, likes };
});
```

This returns an array of Promises. However, the for-loop equivalent does the job.

Is there a way to better implement this rather than having to loop through the entire collection and fetching the `likes` for each one?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question was almost one year ago, in order to help future visitors, the solution you might need could be **population()** method of the mongoose.

> Population, specifies paths that should be populated with other documents.

```
let book = await Book.findOne().populate('authors');
book.title; // 'Node.js in Action'
book.authors[0].name; // 'TJ Holowaychuk'
book.authors[1].name; // 'Nathan Rajlich'

let books = await Book.find().populate({
  path: 'authors',
  // `match` and `sort` apply to the Author model,
  // not the Book model. These options do not affect
  // which documents are in `books`, just the order and
  // contents of each book document's `authors`.
  match: { name: new RegExp('.*h.*', 'i') },
  sort: { name: -1 }
});
books[0].title; // 'Node.js in Action'
// Each book's `authors` are sorted by name, descending.
books[0].authors[0].name; // 'TJ Holowaychuk'
books[0].authors[1].name; // 'Marc Harter'

books[1].title; // 'Professional AngularJS'
// Empty array, no authors' name has the letter 'h'
books[1].authors; // []
```

Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: thanks for your response. Population only populates fields in the same table. However, I later figured out that what I needed was to 'lookup' other tables.

`const authors = await Posts.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: 'authors', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'post', as: 'authors' }}])`